# Keras Bidirectional LSTM: low training and validation loss but very bad predictions

Tags: python, keras, nlp, lstm, prediction

I'm training a `Bidirectional LSTM` using `Keras`. 
My task is to predict the words order in a sentence, so, given a sentence, output of each timestep will be a real number: predicted real numbers of the sentence are ranked in order to obtain integer numbers, indicating the predicted position of the word in the sentence.

Example:

sentence -> "Nice I am"

predicted real numbers -> [0.2, 0.6, 0.4]

ranked real numbers -> [3,1,2]

Basically, I pad my sequences to 20, that is the max sequence length found in the dataset.

My model is the following:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(Masking(mask_value=0., input_shape=(timesteps, features)))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units=timesteps, return_sequences=True), input_shape=(timesteps, features)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
```

I mask all the padded vectors to avoid noise in learning.
My training loss and my validation loss, during the training, are both low and around 0.33.

In the prediction phase, however, I obtain very bad results.
I don't think my model is overfitting/underfitting looking at losses trend.

Is there something bad in my model architecture?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with "I don't think my model is overfitting/underfitting due to losses trend"? Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: @Leevo I know that in general, overfitting is when validation loss is much greater than training loss, and underfitting is when training loss is much greater than validation loss. And looking to my losses, it seems that my model has a good fit. Isn't it?

Comment: @Leevo my training set are ordered sentences, but my test set, of course, are unordered sentences. Could `shuffle=True` improve predictions?